# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ converges

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying for an exit exam and it's been years since I work with any series expansions. Here's a past problem:

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$$ converges to an analytic function on the set $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1 \}$.

I'm looking to use Taylor's theorem for this problem but how would I compute the radius of convergence? Do I have to do a comparison test?

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai No. I don't know how to use it with this rational function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le be $0\le r<1$. If $|z|=r$:
$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\le\frac{r^n}{1-r^2}$$
and $\sum\frac{r^n}{1-r^2}$ converges.

Is not a power series, so the set where converges is not necessarily a disk.

If $|z|=1$:
$$\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\not\to 0$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ isn't convergent.

But if $|z|>1$,
$$\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\approx\frac{1}{z^n}$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ converges again.

Comment: Can I do the same technique you just did to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$ converges to $H= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)>1 \}$ also?

Comment: Yes. $|n^z|=\cdots$.

Comment: $n^{|z|}$ which converges?

Comment: $\sum 1/n^{\Re z}$.

Comment: $|\frac{1}{n^z}|=\frac{1}{n^{|z|}}=\frac{1}{n^{Re(z)}}$ and since $Re(z)>1$, the series converges.

Comment: lol why all the dots? I feel like i'm wrong by all the dots! :-)

Comment: A comment requires 15 characters of more.

Comment: For the case $|z| > 1$ you can substitute $z = 1/w$, with $\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}} = \frac{w^n}{1+w^{2n}}$.

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\le\frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^{2n}}\sim_\infty|z|^n$$
and the geometric series 
$$\sum_n |z|^n$$
is convergent so the given series is absolutely convergent for $|z|<1$.