# Question on a Previous Post about the Sum of Series

Tags: complex-analysis

The post in question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777524/showing-that-sum-n-1-infty-fraczn1z2n-converges). In the comments, it is shown further that it converges for $|z|\neq 1$ However, no one answers how to show it converges to an analytic function in this region. Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an open set $\Omega\subseteq \Bbb C$, recall that the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$;
2. $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ is continuous, and for all $z_0\in \Omega$ there is an open disk $\Delta(z_0,r)\subseteq \Omega$ such that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz=0$ for all (say) piecewise linear closed paths $\gamma:[a,b]\to \Delta(z_0,r)$;
3. $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ is continuous, and $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz$ for all $z_0\in\Omega$, all open disks $\Delta(x_0,r)\subseteq \Omega$ and all piecewise linear closed paths $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Delta(z_0,r)$.

This is essentially Morera's theorem plus the fact that holomorphy is a local property. A consequence of this is that if $f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions $\Omega\to \Bbb C$ which converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, then their limit $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. In fact let $z_0\in \Omega$, let $K\subseteq\Omega$ be compact and $r>0$ such that $\Delta(z_0,r)\subseteq K^\circ$, and let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Delta(z_0,r)$ be a piecewise linear closed path. $f$ is obviously continuous. By (3), $\int_\gamma f_n(z)\,dz=0$ for all $n$, so that $$0\le\left\lvert\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right\rvert=\left\lvert\int_\gamma f(z)-f_n(z)\,dz\right\rvert\le \int_a^b \lvert f(\gamma(t))-f_n(\gamma(t))\rvert M_\gamma\,dt\le\\\le M_\gamma(b-a)\sup_{z\in K}\lvert f(z)-f_n(z)\rvert\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$$

where $M_\gamma$ is a constant that depends only on $\gamma$. Therefore, $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=0$ and $f$ satifies (2). Therefore, $f$ is holomorphic.

This applies to the sequence of partial sums, with the open set $\Omega=\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \lvert z\rvert\ne 1\}$. For uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\Omega$, you can use Weierstrass M-test and the estimates given in the answers (e.g. user Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla's)

Answer (score 0):

It has a Taylor series that converges to it inside $|z|\lt1$ and a Laurent series that converges to it outside the circle.

Comment: Notice though that the series in the original question is neither a Taylor series nor a Laurent series.

Comment: Oh.  Whoops.  Each term has a Taylor or Laurent series... For each n, $z^n$ appears at most $n$ times in the combined Taylor series, so has a definite coefficient bounded above by $n$.  The combined Taylor series is absolutely convergent.  Now I need the remainder term to go to zero.

Comment: Given $N$, there are $N$ terms whose Taylor expansion has begun, and whose combined remainder is bounded above by $N|z|^N/(1-|z|^N)$.  The remaining terms are bounded above by $|z|^k/(1-|z|^N)$ which is geometric.  Both those parts go to zero.